# UIWebView does not show AlertView as per image

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uialertview

I have to update my app to handle the situation as per the image shown. It used to work when I logged into the website and the login for was just displayed as a normal website.

But now since the update it comes up as a UIAlertView, I have seen this similar when I log into my router at home.

However the UIWebView in my app does not show this alert. Mobile Safari does show this.

Is there any way to get the UIWebView to show this or is it just suppose to come up when required?

[image: Example Image]